# Rewrite /keyword1+keyword2.html to search page | .htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess, rewrite-rules, apache

I am facing trouble redirecting the keywords to search page in a wordpress  4.4 setup. What I am trying achieve is to rewrite/redirect

```
www.site.com/**search+keyword.html***
```

to

```
www.site.com/**?s=search+keyword&submit=Search
```

I have tried every solution found in google but none works with this version.

.htaccess file:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ([^/]+)\.html$ ./?s=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

I can search wordpress using: `http://localhost/wordpress/search/keyword`, but I am unable to change the search URL.

What I need is to fire a search whenever there is a keyword followed by a `.html` in the URL. How can I get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Don't touch the .htaccess file, there's this neat tool [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) which you should hook into `init`:

```
add_action('init', function() {

    add_rewrite_rule(
        'search+([^/]+).html$',
        'index.php?my_custom_search=1&s=$matches[1]&submit=Search',
        'top'
    );

});
```

Right after that you should flush the rewrite rules once ( by saving the permalink settings in Settings > Permalinks or with `flush_rewrite_rules()` BUT call that function only once and when needed ).

This should make `www.site.com/search+keyword.html` serve search results as `www.site.com/?s=search+keyword&submit=Search`